# How to focus first input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a ASP.NET MVC application and I want to focus the first field in error. On submit, if the last field has error and user tries to submit the form, the focus is going to the last field in error instead of the first field. I tried multiple including the below:

```
$().ready(function() {
    $("#Form").submit(function() {
        $('.input-validation-error').focus();
        $(".input-validation-error").each(function() {
            $(this).focus();
        });

    });
});
```

Is there any solution where the user can always go to the first field in error.

Comment: You are looping through each element with the `input-validation-error` class and calling focus on it. What did you expect would happen? Why would you loop through all elements if you only want to focus on one of them? Think through your code, think about if it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

No need to use each here and loop over all errors. You can just set the focus to `first` element with error class `input-validation-error` like:

```
$('.input-validation-error:first').focus();
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This solution does not work if the focus is still on the last error. The focus still goes to the last error if the last error is in focus. I am trying to get to the first error in form on the click event.

Answer (score 0):

@Palash has a good answer but I will explain why your code does not work so you understand it.

You need to leave the loop after the focus is set to the first item by returning  false like below:

```
$(".input-validation-error").each(function () {
    $(this).focus();
    return false;
});
```

When you return false, you are instructing jQuery to stop processing the rest of the elements.Otherwise, it will keep looping and you will end up focusing the last item.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eq` method.

> `eq` method reduces the set of matched elements to the one at the
>   specified index.

```
$('.input-validation-error').eq(0).focus();
```