# Focus first error field button click asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a ASP.NET MVC application and I want to focus the first field in error. On click, if the last field has error and user tries to click the save button, the focus is going to the last field in error instead of the first field. I tried multiple including the below:

```
    $('#Save').click(function () {
        $(".input-validation-error").each(function () {
            $(this).focus();
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Is there any solution where the user can always go to the first field in error. Also if the form has other types of errors like field-validation-errors etc, how to take the user to the first error?

Comment: This appears to be attempting to solve the same issue about which you asked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46652237/3773011) a couple of hours prior to this question. While their are not *exactly* the same, they are essentially the same question. Please do not post duplicates of your own questions.

Comment: Further, this question is about JavaScript/HTML/CSS, so you should consider using a [snippet](//blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Using a snippet with a full example of the problem would make it considerably easier for people to understand what your issue is and provide answers which directly address your problem. It also tends to result in more people up-voting your question and/or answer, as they can try it out for themselves.

Comment: I wasn't able to edit my previous question and that was the reason I had to post the question again. I also think this is more related to asp,net mvc.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work:

```
 $('#Save').click(function () {
    var firstError = $(".input-validation-error")[0];

    if(firstError != null){
     $(firstError).focus();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I created an example here :

```js
$('#Save').click(function () {
var save ="";
       $(".input").each(function () {
         if($(this).val() == ""){
            $(this).focus();
            return false;
            
            }
           save++;
        });
         
     if(save== $(".input").length){console.log("save");}   
    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id=Save>save</button><br /><br />

<input class=input type=text><input class=input type=text><input class=input type=text><input class=input type=text><input class=input type=text>
```

So , if validation is true the action will be done otherwise it will focus on first input that has error .